# Get value of an array given a certain condition in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, conditional-statements

I have the array

```
array = [
  { period: 1, currency: 1, cost: 100, count: 10 },
  { period: 1, currency: 2, cost: 200, count: 10 },
  { period: 2, currency: 1, cost: 300, count: 20 },
  { period: 3, currency: 3, cost: 400, count: 30 }
]
```

and I need you to sum the `cost` for the case that has the same `period` and different `currency`, but that does not sum the `count` and that the result is either of the two since they will be the same for the same `period`.

For example:

```
period = 1, sum(cost) = 300 y count = 10
period = 2, sum(cost) = 300 y count = 20
period = 3, sum(cost) = 400 y count = 30
```

How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You will want to iterate over the array and group based on your requirements. You'll most likely want to look into using "array.reduce". What is the expected behaviour if the period and currency are the same for 2 entries?

Comment: @Nick Try to do it in two parts, on the one hand the sum of the costs for the same period, and on the other a function to reduce the array and obtain the count of each period.

Comment: @MateuszSiniarsk iYes, you have to use reduce, there are not two entries or more for the same period and currency. how can I correctly use reduce to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to accomplish the task without using loops inside other loops. `result` ends up being an object that has a key for each period.

```js
const array = [
  { period: 1, currency: 1, cost: 100, count: 10 },
  { period: 1, currency: 2, cost: 200, count: 10 },
  { period: 2, currency: 1, cost: 300, count: 20 },
  { period: 3, currency: 3, cost: 400, count: 330 }
];

const result = array.reduce((all, el) => {
  if (all[el.period]) {
    all[el.period].cost += el.cost;
  } else {
    all[el.period] = { ...el };
  }
  return all;
}, {});

console.log(result[1]);
console.log(result[2]);
console.log(result[3]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this solution using given functional Array methods.

```js
let array = [
  { period: 1, currency: 1, cost: 100, count: 10 },
  { period: 1, currency: 2, cost: 200, count: 10 },
  { period: 2, currency: 1, cost: 300, count: 20 },
  { period: 3, currency: 3, cost: 400, count: 330 },
];

const newArray = array.reduce((acc, elem) => {
  if (acc.some((accElem) => accElem.period === elem.period)) {
    return acc;
  }
  elem.sumCost = array
    .filter((e) => e.period === elem.period)
    .reduce((acc, e) => acc + e.cost, 0);
  return acc.concat(elem);
}, []);

console.log(newArray);
```

the count, currency and cost variable equals fields of first element in matching variables.

Comment: I might recommend not leaving the `cost` key in the final array because it has no real meaning in the aggregate. Also, this seems like it might be fairly inefficient at scale (loops inside of loops). I doubt this problem is at a scale where that matters, but still reasonable to try to avoid if possible.